# Unable to remotely debug a Silverlight application (Mac <-> PC)

Tags: silverlight, remote-debugging

Having set up my Mac and PC per [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903948%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), I am nevertheless unable to attach to the process running in OS X.

"Unable to attach to the process. A debug component is not installed."

Anyone seen this before?  I've Googled it, turned up nothing.

Comment: Which Silverlight version are you trying to debug? All I am finding when googling this are references to Silverlight 2. Maybe this just doesn't work for later versions?

Comment: I'm trying to debug Silverlight 5.  I haven't found any information about whether remote debugging on a Mac is unsupported after Silvelight 2.

Comment: Me neither. But I haven't found anything to suggest that it is supported either. I am guessing that this is the application that you install on the mac: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=119973. The name of the file is "Silverlight.2.0_Developer.dmg", which would suggest that it is specific for Silverlight 2.0. Unless MS have updated those tools for versions 3, 4 and 5 am inclined to think that it only works on SL 2.0.

Comment: No, that's not what I installed.  I installed this:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229325

The link specifically indicates Silverlight 5.

(I got the link from this search result, by the way:

https://www.google.com/search?q=silverlight+5+developer+runtime+mac)

Comment: Yep, looks like you are right. I have no idea why it is not working. Unfortunately it appears to be a feature that gets very little use, so it may be difficult to find reliable information about it. Is there a specific issue that requires you to debug on the mac?

Comment: Well, my employer was itching to have the issue resolved, so I went ahead and debugged it the old-fashioned way (asserts, MessageBox.Show, etc.).  Sure would be nice to be able to debug it in a more modern fashion, though.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same error message on my machine after I had windows update install a security update for Silverlight on windows. I think the root cause is different versions of the silverlight runtime. I recommend doing the following:

Make sure that both windows and mac have the developer runtime installed, and that it is the same version. The latest ones are here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36946

After doing that, relaunch the configuration generating program on OSX, generate a new configuration (top button), and then generate a new PC configuration (bottom button).

Close visual studio, run the configuration exe on windows, and open visual studio.

I followed these steps and was able to get remote debugging working again.